# How to get list of all Image files in Watchkit Extension

Tags: xcode, swift, watchkit, nsfilemanager

I added images file to Watchkit Extension like this:

[image]

I want to get all images file Path of those Images. How can I do that?
I tried

```
let applicationDic = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory( NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)[0] as! NSURL
println("document:\(applicationDic)")
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is if you don't need to do it programmatically: right click (command click) the photo, press "Open with external editor," and then on the right side of the screen you will see "Full Path" about an inch or two down the screen. That is the path to that photo!